# Joomla: remove old alias

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting, seo, duplicates, joomla-sef-urls

After modifying the alias for an article (with SEF enabled), the URL that uses the old alias is still working; I can now 
access the article via:
http://joomlasite.loc/72-pb-details-page
http://joomlasite.loc/72-details-page

I have deleted all entries in the database containing "pb-details-page". How can I deactivate the old URL? What could be causing this?

My Joomla version is 2.5.

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** It seems that the article is displayed according to the ID: for example,
    http://joomlasite.loc/72-details-page
http://joomlasite.loc/72-aaaa
http://joomlasite.loc/72
will all access the same article page.

Comment: yes that's how joomla works, it won't take the alias into consideration (that's why they put the id there). You might want to handle the old names in the redirect component

Comment: Yes.. Thank you. In the end I used the Simple Custom Redirect plugin: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/21251, adding rules via regular expressions.